TemplateResponse context data not displaying in template after POST request
After a POST request, I'm trying to display some data on the template. I don't get yet why it's not displaying.
home.jinja template
<section class="order-interface">
    <div class="order-parameters">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('generate_meal_recipe')}}" id="order-form">
            <label for="cuisineType">Choose your preferred cuisine(s) if any:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="american">  American<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="asian">  Asian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="british">  British<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="caribbean">  Caribbean<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="central europe">  Central Europe<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="chinese">  Chinese<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="eastern europe">  Eastern Europe<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="french">  French<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="indian">  Indian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="italian">  Italian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="japanese">  Japanese<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="kosher">  Kosher<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="mediterranean">  Mediterranean<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="mexican">  Mexican<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="middle eastern">  Middle Eastern<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="nordic"> ❄️ Nordic<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="south american">  South American<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="south east asian">  South East Asian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuisineType" value="world">  World<br>

            <label for="mealType">Choose the type of meal:</label><br>
            <select name="mealType" id="mealType">
                <option value="breakfast">Breakfast</option>
                <option value="brunch">Brunch</option>
                <option value="dinner">Dinner</option>
                <option value="snack">Snack</option>
                <option value="teatime">Teatime</option>
            </select>

            <label for="diet">Choose your diet if any:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="balanced">  Balanced<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="high-fiber">  High Fiber<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="high-protein">  High Protein<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="low-carb">  Low Carb<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="low-fat">  Low Fat<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="diet" value="low-sodium">  Low Sodium<br>

            <label for="health">Choose your health preferences if any:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="alcohol-cocktail">  Alcohol Cocktail<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="alcohol-free">  Alcohol Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="celery-free">  Celery Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="crustacean-free">  Crustacean Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="dairy-free">  Dairy Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="DASH"> DASH<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="egg-free">  Egg Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="fish-free">  Fish Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="fodmap-free"> FODMAP Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="gluten-free">  Gluten Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="immuno-supportive"> Immuno Supportive<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="keto-friendly"> Keto Friendly<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="kidney-friendly"> Kidney Friendly<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="kosher">  Kosher<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="low-fat-abs"> Low Fat Abs<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="low-potassium"> Low Potassium<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="low-sugar"> Low Sugar<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="lupine-free"> Lupine Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="Mediterranean">  Mediterranean<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="mollusk-free"> Mollusk Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="mustard-free"> Mustard Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="no-oil-added"> No Oil Added<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="paleo">  Paleo<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="peanut-free">  Peanut Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="pescatarian"> Pescatarian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="pork-free"> Pork Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="red-meat-free"> Red Meat Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="sesame-free"> Sesame Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="shellfish-free"> Shellfish Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="soy-free"> Soy Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="sugar-conscious"> Sugar Conscious<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="sulfite-free"> Sulfite Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="tree-nut-free">  Tree Nut Free<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="vegan">  Vegan<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="vegetarian">  Vegetarian<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="health" value="wheat-free">  Wheat Free<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    {% if recipe %}
        <div>{{recipe}}</div>
    {% endif %}
</section>

script.js
document
    .getElementById("order-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let q = document.getElementById("q").value;
        // Convert selected checkboxes to list
        // cuisineType
        let cuisineType_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("cuisineType");
        let cuisineType = Array.from(cuisineType_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
        // mealType
        let mealType = [document.getElementById("mealType").value];
        // diet
        let diet_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("diet");
        let diet = Array.from(diet_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
        // health
        let health_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("health");
        let health = Array.from(health_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

        let form_data = {
            q: q,
            cuisineType: cuisineType,
            mealType: mealType,
            diet: diet,
            health: health,
        };

        // Send the data to the server
        fetch("/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form_data),
        })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("order-form").reset(); // Reset the form
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
    });

main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class Order(BaseModel):
    """Order object."""

    q: str
    cuisineType: Optional[List[str]] = []
    mealType: Optional[List[str]] = []
    diet: Optional[List[str]] = []
    health: Optional[List[str]] = []



@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request) -> Response:
    """Home page."""
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.jinja", {"request": request})

@app.post("/")
async def generate_meal_recipe(request: Request, order: Order) -> Response:
    """Retrieve generated meal recipe."""
    # Logic
    recipe = "abc"

    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.jinja", context={"request": request, "recipe": recipe})

When submitting the form, I should be able to see recipe value (abc) on my template. Weirdly, I'm not. When using the browser dev tools (inspecting Network), I find the Response to the request with the data displayed. Why am I not seeing it directly? Does it have anything to do with the script?

The issue is with the JS code. I was preventing the default form action and just logged the fetched data in the console. An update of the script by updating the page allows the data to be displayed :
script.js
document
    .getElementById("order-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let q = document.getElementById("q").value;
        // Convert selected checkboxes to list
        // cuisineType
        let cuisineType_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("cuisineType");
        let cuisineType = Array.from(cuisineType_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
        // mealType
        let mealType = [document.getElementById("mealType").value];
        // diet
        let diet_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("diet");
        let diet = Array.from(diet_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
        // health
        let health_checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("health");
        let health = Array.from(health_checkboxes)
            .filter((checkbox) => checkbox.checked)
            .map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

        let form_data = {
            q: q,
            cuisineType: cuisineType,
            mealType: mealType,
            diet: diet,
            health: health,
        };

        // Send the data to the server
        fetch("/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form_data),
        })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                document.getElementById("order-form").reset(); // Reset the form
                // Update the whole page with the new data
                document.open();
                document.write(data);
                document.close();
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
    });


An alternative would be to use FastApi dependencies with the Request object directly to do the reformatting of the form fields I'm doing with the script. It would look like this :
main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Depends
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional, Annotated

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class Order(BaseModel):
    """Order object."""

    q: str
    cuisineType: Optional[List[str]] = []
    mealType: Optional[List[str]] = []
    diet: Optional[List[str]] = []
    health: Optional[List[str]] = []

@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request) -> Response:
    """Home page."""
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.jinja", {"request": request})


async def reformat_form_fields(request: Request):
    """Reformat submitted form fields so it could comply with API parameters type."""
    async with request.form() as form:
        q = form.get("q")
        cuisineType = form.getlist("cuisineType") if "cuisineType" in form else []
        mealType = form.getlist("mealType") if "mealType" in form else []
        diet = form.getlist("diet") if "diet" in form else []
        health = form.getlist("health") if "health" in form else []
    
    order = Order(q=q, cuisineType=cuisineType, mealType=mealType, diet=diet, health=health)
    return order


@app.post("/")
async def generate_meal_recipe(
    request: Request, order: Annotated[Order, Depends(reformat_form_fields)]
) -> Response:
    """Retrieve generated meal recipe."""
        # Logic
    recipe = "abc"

    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.jinja", context={"request": request, "recipe": recipe})

